# JPQL: how to retrieve a List of data and set a value for each data in that list

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

So I have a entity `Notification`, that has a boolean attribute `readStatus` to determine of a notification has been read or not. When I click a button, I want to write a JPQL that retrieve the unread notifications (`readStaus=false`) and set the `readStatus` of those unread notifications to `true`

**Note: I dont want to write jpql to retrieve the list and manually loop through the list to set the `readStatus` and merge them back to the database**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
UPDATE Notification n SET n.readStatus = true WHERE n.readStatus = false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Notification> notifications = 
    em.createQuery("select n from Notification n where n.readStatus = false")
      .getResultList();
for (Notification n : notifications) {
    n.setReadStatus(true);
}
```

Comment: I know this. I am asking I can do this with JPQL. Because you have to persist every notification object inside that for loop. So I wonder if I can do this in JPQL and avoid all the overhead